# OrientDB SQL: Retrieve vertices with non-zero degree

Tags: sql, graph, orientdb2.2

I would like to retrieve all vertices in a SQL query that have at least one connection (non-zero degree).  Just returning the rid is probably OK, but it would be nice to select properties too.

The edges have "in" and "out" properties, so I could make a set of those.  I'm not sure how to do this with OrientDB sql.

Also, I thought there would be some way to do it more naturally by querying vertices directly.  I see the vertices have IN and OUT recorded, and the edge Class name underneath.  But I do not know how to access the vertex IN and OUT in a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do the trick

```
SELECT FROM V WHERE both().size() > 0
```

If you need additional properties or additional filters, you can just add them to the query, eg.

```
SELECT property1, property2 FROM V WHERE both().size() > 0 and foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

IN and OUT are accessed with `in()` and `out()`.  These can go right after `SELECT` to retrieve them, or, in the predicate as where Luigi has used `both()` (short for `in()` and `out()`).

The complete list of "graphy" functions is in the docs, [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/master/SQL-Functions.html#functions-by-category), in the first column.